# Clojure: How does Clojure know when a reference is actually a macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

Binding to variables come from let expressions, imports and probably there are other sources (I'm a beginner in Clojure). So it's not trivial to know something references a macro.

I still don't know when are macros expanded, but given the dynamic nature of Clojure I'd say they're expanded during interpretation(?), but then, how does Clojure know that the passed parameters shouldn't be evaluated, but instead passed as a AST?

Is there documentation that thoroughly explains how it works?

Answer (score 3):

Macros are just vars that resolve to a function and have the value for `:macro` key in their metadata set to `true`. You can see how it is set in the [definition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L487) of `defmacro`.

Therefore, you can get this data directly from the metadata:

```
user=> (:macro (meta #'let))
true
```

Alternatively, you can just use a [getter](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L249) to check whether a var is a macro:

```
user=> (.isMacro #'let)
true
user=> (.isMacro #'inc)
false
```

> [...] but then, how does Clojure know that the passed parameters shouldn't be evaluated, but instead passed as a AST?

During [macroexpansion](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4090f405466ea90bbaf3addbe41f0a6acb164dbb/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6985), the Clojure Compiler calls the `.isMacro` [on the var](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4090f405466ea90bbaf3addbe41f0a6acb164dbb/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6902).

Comment: So 'let' is a macro? that's very confusing

Comment: Why is it confusing? Several fundamental Clojure elements are macros; if you think about it, `when` has to be, because it only evaluates its body when the condition is true, which is not normal function call semantics. And even more than macros, some are special forms, which the compiler knows to handle specially. https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms (and remember you can see the source for `let` by typing `(source let)` in the REPL in the user namespace).

Comment: `let` is a macro which is implemented using the `let*` special form. wrapping the special form in a macro made it easy to add destructuring to it while keeping the implementation simple.

Answer (score 1):

As the Clojure documentation [describes](https://clojure.org/reference/macros), macros “allow the compiler to be extended by user code.” This is quietly telling us when it happens during the read-eval-print-loop you’ve probably heard discussed for Lisp-like languages. The first stage reads a string and converts it into the Clojure data structures that it represents (what you called an AST, but since Lisp dialects are homoiconic, there is a closer relationship between the source and the parsed data structures than one usually finds in an AST).

It is during the second stage, evaluation, when the compiler is turning the parsed structures into Java byte code that can actually be loaded and run, that macros come into play. When the compiler finds a var that references a macro, it calls that macro function with the parsed code that is found inside the body of that expression, and then replaces the macro invocation with whatever data structures the macro returns. It then goes on to compile the result, which may involve more macro expansions, but eventually boils down to byte code. In this way, macros can fundamentally change and extend the language, which makes them powerful, but it also makes them challenging to write because you need to keep completely separate hierarchies of abstraction in mind simultaneously, and relate the structures being compiled to the results that exist later at runtime.

This also means that, unlike normal Clojure functions, macros are not first-class; you can’t pass them to other functions to form higher-order constructs, because by the time compilation is finished, the macro no longer exists, it has been replaced by whatever it returned. This is why you will see the error “Cannot take value of a macro” when you try to pass one as an argument to another function.

And as another answer has explained, the compiler can tell when it is compiling a macro because of metadata attached to the var that holds the macro.

If you really want to go deep in understanding the fundamental role macros play in Lisps, [Let Over Lambda](https://letoverlambda.com) is an interesting read.